# Load data with JSON in for loop

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I have next question for You. My code looks like:

```
var data=[];
for(i=0;i<parametrTable.length;++i){
    x = parametrTable[i];
    (function(i) {
        if(i==0){
            $.getJSON("myurlwithparametr", function(json) {
                $.each(json, function(j, d){
                    data.push({"column0": d.column, "count0": d.count});
                 });
             });
         }
         else{
              $.getJSON("myurlwithparametr", function(json) {
                $.each(json, function(j, d){
                    data[j]["count"+i] = d.count});
              });
         }
         })(i);
   }
```

To 'data' array loading individual values received from JSON'a. I think the problem lies in the variable 'i' loop because the load asynchronously. Do you have an idea how to avoid this?

Comment: i assume that "myurlwithparametr" is not the real url but you changed it to not be shown on Stackoverflow right?

Comment: I wonder how many questions you can have.. Is this some sort of Quiz?

Comment: what is the expected result and what you are getting?

Comment: Try to assing post-incremented ```i++``` every time you need it instead of increment it in loop.

Comment: Use a **each** loop here.. refer to the link here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: When the loop to the end, I would like to make 'data' look:
[column0: value, count0: value, count1: value ... counti: value
column2: value: count0: value, count1: value ... counti: value
columnn: value ... etc.]

Comment: You understand that this will kick off a bunch of http requests, and there's no guarantee that the first one will finish before the second one. however, your code relies on the first one loading first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should take care of ensuring the first JSON is loaded and processed before processing all others as they come (in any order)

```
var data = [];
x = parametrTable[0];
$.getJSON("myurlwithparametr", function(json) { ... get first data
    $.each(json, function(j, d) { // ... process first data
        data.push({
            "column0": d.column,
            "count0": d.count
        });
    });
    $.each(parametrTable, function(i, x) { // NOTE: x is now populated here
        if (i) { // run from 1 ... end after 1st JSON is done
            $.getJSON("myurlwithparametr", function(json) {
                $.each(json, function(j, d) {
                    data[j]["count" + i] = d.count;
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

a better / cleaner alternative

```
var data = [];
$.each(parametrTable, function(i, x) { // NOTE: x = parametrTable[i]
    $.getJSON("myurlwithparametr", function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(j, d) {
            data[j] = data[j] || {};
            data[j]["count" + i] = d.count;
            if (i == 0) {
                data[j].column0 = d.column;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think that 'x' should be before the first getJSON. I will check

Comment: You are correct, the x is used in the url+parameters no doubt - which isn't obvious in the code :p - check the edit for a cleaner version though

Comment: And this solution ended my problem. :) Thank You ! :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need.

```
var data=[];
parametrTable.forEach(function (x, i){
    if(i==0) {
        $.getJSON("/url/with/params?params", function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(j, d) {
                data.push({"column0": d.column, "count0": d.count});
             });
         });
     }
     else{
          $.getJSON("myurlwithparametr", function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(j, d){
                data[j]["count"+i] = d.count
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: it's `forEach`, not, capital E, and then there's no need for the IIFE at all

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the update.. I updated the code for **forEach** but I have no idea what you meant by IIFE here. Would you please explain?

Comment: Oh I get it.. But let the OP change it. I just wanted to guide him in the right path. He can now do his research and get that sorted out.

Comment: also, forEach, the first paramater in the callback is the item, second is the index :p

Comment: instead if `item, i` do `x, i` then remove the `x = parametrTable[i]` :p

Comment: However, your answer is no different to the question - the fundamental flaw is assuming the first getJSON will finish first

Comment: @JaromandaX I'd say let the OP figure that out. The whole intention behind the answer here is that the OP should be able to understand the foreach functionality

Comment: The problem is, you've done exactly the same flawed code in a different manner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91741/discussion-between-akshay-khandelwal-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 0):

This should make the calls in sequence, that is, the next call won't start unless the previous one is completed. You might still need to check when the call is completed in your other code

```
var data=[];
getDataParametr(data, parametrTable, 0); 
function getDataParametr(data, parametrTable, i){
  x = parametrTable[i];
  var url="myurlwithparametr";
  $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    if(i==0){  
      $.each(json, function(j, d){data.push({"column0": d.column, "count0": d.count});});
    } else {
      $.each(json, function(j, d){data[j]["count"+i] = d.count});
    }
    if(++i<parametrTable.length){
      getDataParametr(data, parametrTable, i);
    }
  });
}
```